# Linear Algebra - Solving Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in the middle of calculating nutrients for my diet, but I stumbled across a math problem. Specifically matrix multiplication problem

Here's my daily nutrients goal (ignore the units for now):

1. Protein: 174
2. Carbs: 174
3. Fat: 39
4. Calories: 1737
5. Sodium: 2300

And then I compiled a list of meals I usually cook. Each row represents the meal nutrients per 1 serving. For example:

\begin{bmatrix}&|&Protein&Carbs&Fat&Calories&Sodium\\meal1&|&0&4&0&5&144\\meal2&|&4&23.9&1.8&129&260\\meal3&|&0&26&0&100&20\\meal4&|&20&37&21&400&300\\meal5&|&33.8&0&18.5&311&100\\meal6&|&4.6&46.7&1.6&222&2\\meal7&|&55&11.2&0.1&0.6&64\\meal8&|&33.8&0&18.5&311&100\\meal9&|&4.6&46.7&1.6&222&2\\meal10&|&55&11.2&0.1&0.6&64\end{bmatrix}

Now, I want to tweak the number of servings of these meals so they approximate my daily nutrients goal. A decimal number of servings is fine for me (i.e, 0.8 serving of *meal1*)

I think essentially what I'm trying to do is to solve **x** in the following system:
$$x A = y$$

where **x** is the vector of the number of servings, A is the nutrients matrix, and **y** is my daily nutrients goal (i.e., `[174 174 39 1737 2300]`)

This is probably a trivial question, but I don't know how to solve it without trial and error. I tried to google this problem, but I couldn't get an answer because I don't know what math keywords to look for exactly.

Comment: Take a look at [Gaussian elimination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: This seems more like a linear programming problem rather than a system of linear equations for which you should find an exact solution. Your nutrient targets are likely really inequalities: e.g., you’d probably be OK with getting less than 2300 units of Na if all of the other targets are satisfied. If you do want to solve the equation, look up Gaussian elimination aka row-reduction but be aware: there might not be a solution at all, but if there is, then there will be an infinite number of them with at least 5 free variables. If there is no solution, you could try a least-squares fit.

Comment: Isn't this a homework ?

Comment: No, I'm working on my diet plan..

Answer (score 1):

There is an algebraic method to solve this problem. 
You could use a generalized inverse ($B$), to obtain

$$ xA = y \implies x A B = x = y B  $$

The matrix $B$ can be a right inverse of $A$, $\left(B = A_R^{-1}\right)$, or a generalized inverse, such as a Penrose inverse. In either case, $xAB = x I_n = x$ which reduces the left side of the equation.

With that said, having more than $5$ meals will likely mean that there is no exact solution, or one that is outside the realistic range of values for the problem context. You have a good example of an overdetermined system, where there are more equations than variables.

In that case, as amd suggested, a least-squares approximation of a solution would be an ideal course of action without modifying the problem. However, a least-squares solution will find the best fit, not necessarily the most practical fit for your problem, especially if different rows have values close to each other. Additionally, you don't need to repeat rows (5/8, 6/9, 7/10), just increase the count in the $x$ vector data.

Including additional columns of nutrient data *might* help with a better approximation, but that's hard to verify without having the real data in $A$.